# How to make child to parent view anchor in snap?

Tags: swift, constraints

I am trying to make a child view exactly the same size as its parent like this code:

```
content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
content.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseBackground.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
content.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseBackground.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseBackground.widthAnchor).isActive = true
content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseBackground.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

I was wondering if there is real short way, not an extension, to do something like this with single line of code:

```
content.anchor = baseBackground
```

or

```
content.anchor.constraint(equalTo: baseBackground).isActive = true
```